# How to export upsell and cross-sell products through programmatically in magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I want to export up-sell and cross-sell products through programmatically.

How it is possible to export up-sell and cross-sell products?

I don't know how to implement this task.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could help if you give them a custom attribut (Cross-sell and up-sell) so you can sort it by the export.

Comment: Hi @ Marcel, Thanks for your response my question.Can you please send me the code.Can you please help me?

Comment: How many products (Cross-sell and up-sell) you want to Export? You need not a code. You have to build for each a attribut (admin>catalog>attribute>new attribute) If you build it you have to put it in your default attribut set.

Comment: Hi,  Can you please send me to refer link.Actually, i don't know how to implement this task.Can you please help me?

Comment: Here is a manual to create a attribute. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDvDRtWD0Ps

Comment: You need a attribut for your default attribut set where you can say yes or no (Cross-sell < Yes/No). After you have put the attribut cross sell  in the default attribut set you can see it in each article with the default attribut set then you have to choose in each article cross-sell yes or no. After that you can sort it in your export.